# Htaccess directive doesn't get applied to all files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added the `.htaccess` directive in the root access file of Joomla.
Now it is working as expected except for files in certain folders.
I checked the folder for the file where it is not applied, but there is no other `.htaccess` file which can override the default `.htaccess` in the root.
Example of the files to which it doesn't get applied is js and css files.

1. These files are from the same source that is not from third party server.
2. These files do not contain any query string.

The directive I am using is like this:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

what else I can check to find out, what may be overriding the directive above.

Comment: What about your Apache Server and Virtual Host configuration?

Comment: That is fine, as I have many other website on the same server and I don't have this problem on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

If these ExpiresByType are not honoured, that means these files are not served by Apache, or there is another override somewhere.

Some joomla plugins may serve css and js dynamically (to add compression or expiration), so that's where you should look out first.
Some webservers use nginx proxy prior to Apache, and css / js files are served by nginx and not Apache. So look at your apache logfiles that it's Apache who served you these files.
Look also once again about your Virtual Host configuration. Not having the problem on other sites on the same server doesn't mean the override isn't on your vhost configuration.

Deactivate PHP, restart server, load these css/js file and see if there's any change. (this is to test if these files are processed by any php script)
Try to load some non-existent css file and analyse your access log.
Shutdown Apache and load the css files (this is to check if you have nginx proxy or something like that).